# Is memory occupied by instances freed when their container is cleared?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

Coming from a c background, I have a question regarding memory management in C#. One of my classes holds a container for a mapped class:

```
public class B
{
     // some data members, constructors, etc...
}

public class A {

    Dictionary<string, B>() m_dictionary;

    // other data members

    public A() { m_dictionary = new Dictionary<string, B>(); }

    // more methods, etc.

    public void clearDictionary() {  m_dictionary.clear(); }
}
```

I understand that once clearDictionary() is called, the garbage collector will eventually free the memory occupied by all those instances of B that lived inside, unless they are referenced somewhere else. Am I right or should I do any additional check to make sure that memory will be freed? thanks

Answer (score 1):

An object is collected when there are no more references to it. If the call to `m_dictionary.clear()` removes the reference to the instance of `B` that was in the dictionary, and there are no more references to that instance anywhere else, then that instance becomes eligible for collection.